# Gridview for XML with Pictures in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, uitableview, gridview

I am building an iPhone app that I would like to be able to have a gallery of images that is loaded from an XML file.  The xml simply has the name of the image, and the link for each image as the exact URL where the image is loaded.  I have looked at a few different examples like, https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView but have a lot of problems customizing it for my use.  The link I gave seems way too in depth for the simple thing I want of parsing an XML (which my code does) and to create a 'thumnbail' for each article, filling in that thumbnail with the image provided in the 'link' category of the XML.  Could someone help me out a little bit?  I am using ASIHTTPREQUEST and GDATAXML libraries  to parse my XML as shown in Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on parsing.

EDIT:  Looking over stuff, I guess I can create a Custom Cell and only have a UIImageView in the custom cell, but how would I write up the code so I can have about 4 columns of pictures across the cell, and have it load a different picture with each?

Comment: store the image views within an array, then access the image view for an index and set the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple solution check out https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser

It works by using a datasource which you define. these can be images or just URLS. it then goes and fetches the URL and displays the image. It also makes it easier to select a single image compared to your way of using a simple UITableView.

Have a look at the samples included it should fit your purpose.

Comment: My current app parses like this:
The RSSEntry class has a method to init different strings for blog title, article titles, URL, and Images.  In the code that parses I set the strings to each one, create a NSMutable array called entries, and add the objects for each string into it.  So then, I could import that into the DataSource for this app, and set the NSMutableArray to the entries.picImage?

Comment: I took a look at this but am having issues as my XML only has one set of URL for pictures, and when I try and do this, I get errors.